# MSDTC Service on SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

How do I Start the MSDTC service on SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator is not "on SQL Server" per se - it is a normal Windows Service. To start it, go to the command prompt and enter:

```
net start msdtc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get access to MSDTC administration UI, go to Administration=>Component Services=>Local Computer. There you'll be able to manage the MSDTC via GUI.